# python - wp2md does not parse source file not well formed

Tags: python, xml, wordpress, xml-parsing

I'm referring to this program:

https://github.com/dreikanter/wp2md

Basically it is used to convert a Wordpress XML into a markdown file.

I implemented it with the cmd the following way:

```
pip install https://github.com/dreikanter/wp2md/zipball/master
```

This worked fine. And it got implemented into my anaconda3 site packages folder:

```
C:\Users\mycomputer\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
```

Then I'm not sure if i did this correctly. I placed the folder with the xml file into the Anaconda folder. Looking like this:

```
C:\Users\mycomputer\Anaconda3\newFolder\WordpressDump.xml
```

Now the github suggests the following:

```
wp2md -d /export/path/ wordpress-dump.xml
```

this is how i did:

```
wp2md -d /newFolder/ wordpress-dump.xml
```

unfortunately I get this error message, that the file could not be parsed because it is not well formed:

```
Parsing WordpressDump.xml...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\mycomputer\anaconda3\Scripts\wp2md-script.py", line 11 in
<module> load entry point ('wp2md==0.8.1', 'console_scripts', 'wp2md')()
File c:\users\mycomputer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wp2md\wp2md.py", 
line 660, in main
parser.feed(text)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParserError: not well formed (invalid token): line
31035, column 80
```

The wordpress xml dump was exported as advised on the [github page](https://github.com/dreikanter/wp2md)

- Do you know if the problem is the wp2md python implementation or the xml export.
- As I'm a complete newbie to python any link or suggestion is highly welcomed how to solve this.